# Delete trigger issue with ON DELETE CASCADE in sql server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, cascading-deletes

I have two Tables in Sql server

```
Table A: Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
Table B: Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
         AId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,ON DELETE CASCADE (This is Id of Table A)
```

(Notice B has column AId that references A with ON DELETE CASCADE option).
B also has a delete trigger like

```
CREATETRIGGER B_Delete_Trigger
ON [dbo].[B]
FOR DELETE
AS
SELECT * FROM DELETED AS B INNER JOIN A ON B.AId=A.Id
```

Now when I perform delete operation on Table B, above trigger returns rows, but when on 
Table A nothing is returned.

As much I know SQL Server first delete records from Child Table(B in this case) and then from parent(A in this case), so above trigger should return some record in both cases.

Please, tell me how to access parents records, Or my observation is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Actually when you call this trigger on table A. The execution sequence is

1. DELETE Record from child table B.
2. DELETE Record from Parent table A.
3. Trigger call

And SELECT * FROM DELETED contains only data from A table.

Comment: This correct and to add a bit more explanation.  Nothing is returned from the SELECT in the trigger because it has an INNER JOIN from B to A and the data in A has GONE by the time the trigger executes due to the CASCADE delete.  Trigger can see deleted data from table B but can't see table A's deleted data.

Answer (score 1):

A "FOR" trigger is equivalent to an "AFTER" trigger. The trigger fires after the delete operation has completed. Therefore, by the time the delete trigger executes for B, the record in table A is already gone. As far as I know, there is no simple way to get access to the record in table A.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the on delete cascade be on the parent table?

The purpose of this is that once the parent is deleted, providing there are other tables referencing the parent of course (via FK constraints), then all the child records will be deleted too. It looks like you have it the wrong way round??

MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933119(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Could not get why I put delete cascade be on the parent table. My aim is whenever there is a delete, either on Table A or on Table B, I want to get all rows produced by above trigger query. I m ready if we can achieve this by putting a trigger on Table A too.

Answer (score 0):

Below items should be noted:

- In case of Parent-Child relational table, always try to create `trigger` on parent table to perform `ON DELETE CASCADE`
- Child table can't CASCADE with Parent.
- `ON DELETE CASCADE` means: when you delete item from Parent table, all items will be deleted from child table with deleted reference.

Hope you've got me, thanks for your time.

Comment: My simple requirement is that,If child Table is deleted due to FK constraints with Parent table, I want to get Parent table records in AFTER DELETE TRIGGER of child table. Can we do that..

Comment: If any record is deleted from Parent table and consequently records will delete from Child table, however to get delete record of the parent table, you do need to create a trigger on parent table(AFTER DELETE TRIGGER) and then select deleted records from `DELETED` table and save it to your physical(existing) table, thanks for your time.